# Primefaces JSF dataTable updating when add new record but records are not saved in database

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

I am using Primefaces 5.3 in my project everything is working fine but sometimes when I add new data to p:datatable it is showing new added records on front-end but records are not saved in database. This is strange behavior, the records on front-end are showing even I clear cache of my browser but gone when I restart my tomcat server. After a lot of tries I came to the point that this happened when there is any exception in batch process. I'll appreciate if any expert can help me in this matter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I`m not sure, but try this  <p:ajax event="change" update="@this:" /> inside the datatable

Comment: does it show something wrong ?!?

Comment: how are you `adding data` to the datatable?

Comment: @Yagami on UI there is nothing wrong everything is working fine. New rows added are shown in the datatable at front-end but in database there is no record saves.

Comment: @Ouerghi I am calling a function on button click in which i explicitly save the object using SQL insert query.

Comment: @JunaidSubhani can you show us that function?